# Get the ID of the dynamically generated textbox which is calling a javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dynamic

I am dynamically generating textboxes in ASP page and suppose they are calling javascript function "foo" on text change. I want to pass the textbox ID calling the function to that javascript function.

i.e. If you are typing in textbox 3, I wanna show that Currently You are typing in txtbox3 (the id of textbox 3)

I have an autocomplete function I dont know how to pass the ID of the calling textbox.. I am using class attribute but it changes the value of every textbox... I want the ID instead of .tbi

Comment: You need to show us how you are calling `foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple answers depend upon how your code works.

If you are attaching the event handler with addEventListener, then you can get the object that generated the event from the `this` pointer like this:

```
obj.addEventListener("change", function() {
    // get the id of the object that triggered the event
    var id = this.id;
    // do whatever you want to with that id
}, false)
```

or using a regular function:

```
function foo(e) {
    // get the id of the object that triggered the event
    var id = this.id;
    // do whatever you want to with that id
}

obj.addEventListener("change", foo, false);
```

or, if you are embedding the event handler directly in the HTML, you can do it like this:

```
<textarea id="xxx" onchange="foo(this)"></textarea>

function foo(obj) {
    // get the id of the object that triggered the event
    var id = obj.id;
    // do whatever you want to with that id
}
```

As is usually the case on stackoverflow, if you show us your actual HTML and javascript, you will get answers specific to your particular situation.

Comment: I have posted the actual function. Its actually a jQuery autocomplete... For the textboxes, they r dynamically created in code behind in the standard way. I will post that code too

Answer (score 0):

That highly depends on how you call `foo`.

Let's assume you use inline `onkeydown="foo();"` on all textboxes. Then you simply change it to `onkeydown="foo.call(this);"`. Then you can use `this` inside foo and access the ID via `this.id`.